# save membership in session variable when authenticated

Tags: c#-3.0

I would like to bound a sqlconnection paramater to a session variable holding the current logged in user, is there an glboal event that triggers whenever the membership user is set/changed so I can set at the event the session variable holding the current logged in user?

Thanks